# Android: Listview SetOnClickListener causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, listview

I have this code in my onCreate method and it causes NullPointerException when the onCreateMethod is called.

```
lvCheckList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
}
```

LogCat: http://pastebin.com/0bU90xbh

I have looked at similar posts by other users but could not find an answer that worked.

EDIT: onCreate Method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.checklist);
    Button bAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddItem);
    final EditText etItemName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etItemName);
    final TextView tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

    //----------------lvCheckList is defined here -------------------
    ListView lvCheckList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCheckLists);
    // lvCheckList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    // lvCheckList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String selectedItem = extras.getString("selectedItem");
        // get the value based on the key
        currentList = selectedItem;
    }
    tvTitle.setText(currentList);
    checkListData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
    updateListView();

    //------------------- OnItemClickListener -----------------------------
    lvCheckList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
```

Comment: lvCheckList is null... Try something like lvChecklist = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); or something before setting a listener.

Comment: See edit...As you can see lvCheckList is defined but it still causes NullPointerException

Comment: Can you post your xml as well? Are you sure R.id.lvCheckLists is a valid id in the inflated layout?

Comment: Ok I found the problem. I had R.id.lvCheckLists and it should be R.id.lvCeckList (no s at the end). Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

That means your `lvCheckList` is null. Make sure you have assigned a value to listview:

```
lvChecklist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_listview);
```